# How to use bash script from another repository in gitlab pipeline?

Tags: bash, git, gitlab, continuous-integration, pipeline

I have two projects in Gitlab. In project A, there are Bash scripts (all located in a single folder). Project B contains a pipeline. How can I implement this? I have already tried using Git submodules, but when I try to initialize and update the submodule in the pipeline, I get an error:

```
Submodule 'a' (https://gitlab-ss.intranet.x.com/a) registered for path 'b'
Cloning into 'a/b'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://gitlab-ss.intranet.x.com': No such device or address
fatal: clone of 'https://gitlab-ss.intranet.x.com/b' into submodule path 'a/b' failed
Failed to clone 'b'.
```

I replaced the real project name by a, b and x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ***one way*** to do it:

1. Clone [**only**](https://medium.com/@judyess/how-to-clone-specific-subdirectory-branch-with-git-3fb02fd35b68) the **folder** (containing the scripts) from **project A** to use it in the pipelines of **project B** using the predefined variable [`CI_JOB_TOKEN`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/ci_job_token.html#use-a-job-token-to-clone-a-private-projects-repository).
   More details about the predefined CI/CD variables can be found [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html).

   ```
    script:
        - |
          git clone --depth 1 --no-checkout https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab-ss.intranet.x.com/namespace/project_name
          cd project_name
          git sparse-checkout set --no-cone scripts_folder
          git checkout
          cd scripts_folder
          ls -a
   ```
2. [Add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72789599/gitlab-ci-cd-execute-script-file-that-exist-in-the-repository) execution permission to your scripts (you probably won't need this)

   ```
      chmod +x script1.sh script2.sh script3.sh
   ```
3. Execute the scripts

   ```
    ./script1.sh
    ./script2.sh
    ./script3.sh
   ```

All of the above, combined together, should be something like this:

```
    script:
        - |
          git clone --depth 1 --no-checkout https://gitlab-ci-token:${CI_JOB_TOKEN}@gitlab-ss.intranet.x.com/namespace/project_name
          cd project_name
          git sparse-checkout set --no-cone scripts_folder
          git checkout
          cd scripts_folder
          ls -a
          chmod +x script1.sh script2.sh script3.sh
         ./script1.sh
         ./script2.sh
         ./script3.sh
```